# Can we have a sequence environment variable in the Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

In the app.yaml I have put:

```
env_variables:
  var1: 18
  var2:
    - 17
    - 16
  var3: True
```

Then in a function in the backend I display these variables from `os.environ`, but I get this:

```
var1: 18
var2: []
var3: True
```

It seems like it doesn't pick up YAML sequences. Am I doing something wrong or does GAE not support these?

Comment: How would you normally, i.e. from the commandline, set an environment variable to be a list? Both on Windows and Unix I know those to be strings only.

Comment: Good point, an environment variable is probably not what I want. Is there a way of storing a list of strings (in the app.yaml or somewhere else) so that it's available on GAE without creating an entity? Defining an entity class just for a list seems like a convoluted solution.

Comment: That's trivial.

Comment: Actually the easiest way is probably to add the list to a script and import it.